# Pouchdb: is there an approved way to prevent ?since=0 calls to _changes feed during pouchdb replication

Tags: pouchdb

Our application has a custom method for performing a fullSync that does not use the couch db replication.

We have recently found that occasionally the pouch db on the device will attempt a fullSync on a device with some initial data which involves calls to **_changes endpoint with ?since=0** which takes a very long time and never succeeds.

Is there way to make the liveSync[sync with live: true] error out when checkpointer returns 0 as the starting point?